# Facing issue while mapping publication for publishing

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, topology-manager

We have restored CM database of our Test environment on our development CMS database. Now while configuring topology mapping I am getting error value already in use. Screenshot showing below:

[image]

I believe issue is because publication ID is changed on both environment. We are unable to remove mapping without unpublishing the content. We don't want to unpublish the content as it require the whole website to publish selectively on dev server again. Is there any way to map the publication with topology without unpublishing the content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the looks of it, your system thinks that this URL (`http://localhost:92`) is already mapped against another Publication.

What I think you need to do is find what that other Publication is and then run the `Set-TtmWebsite` against the Website mapped to that Publication.

For example, if this was the old Development environment:

- Publication Name: Global Website

  - Publication ID: tcm:0-123-1
  - URL: http://localhost:92
- Publication Name: DE Website

  - Publication ID: tcm:0-456-1
  - URL: http://localhost:93

... and then in your restored database, the Publication settings are as follows:

- Publication Name: Global Website

  - Publication ID: tcm:0-999-1
- Publication Name: DE Website

  - Publication ID: tcm:0-123-1 (i.e. this DE Website now has the same TcmId as the old Global Website)

... your system will think that the *DE Website* Publication is mapped to *http://localhost:92*

To fix this, you will first need to update the URL for the DE website:
`Set-TtmWebsite -Id DEWebsiteId -BaseUrls {"http://localhost:93"}`

... this then 'releases' the *http://localhost:92* URL to be used by the Global website using:
`Set-TtmWebsite -Id GlobalWebsiteId -BaseUrls {"http://localhost:92"}`

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that's indeed a cleanest way.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad that it helped and you managed to sort it without having to unpublish and then republish everything!